# How did Gipsy Danger submerge in water?

Tags: pacific-rim

In the “Pacific Rim” movie, how did Gipsy Danger fully submerge underwater in operation “pitfall”? Wouldn’t the water do something to the nuclear reactor? And if it doesn’t, why did Cherno Alpha’s pilots scream “Water is reaching the reactor!”during the double event? Please help me clear this up.

Comment: Maybe it's waterproof, like many electronic devices nowadays?

Comment: Cherno was leaking water into the reactor because it was damaged during the fight.

Comment: I've never seen this movie. Are you seriously telling me the best name they could come up with was Gypsy Danger? And PR was fine with that?

Comment: @Broklynite It's actually "Gipsy Danger", which may have been a reference to the [gipsy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Gipsy) engines used in world war 2. You've also got to remember it was the American Jaeger, the film itself was American, and "gypsy" doesn't carry the same connotations and history here as it does in Europe.

Comment: @Jon Do you think that nuclear reactors are normally exposed to air and water?  Instead they are sealed and they cool off with systems that are sealed but transfer heat to other systems that may be eventually connected to the outside.  And note that the atomic reactors in nuclear submarines - like the air breathing crew - operate normally even when the subs are underwater for months at a time, showing how well they are sealed off from the water outside.  Only various types of leaks cause atomic reactors to have problems with outside air and water.

Comment: @FirstLastname I'm American actually. But that makes a great deal of sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As two of the Jaegers go underwater (aroound 1:45:45), we hear both *Stacker Pentecost* (*acting* lead pilot of *Striker Eureka*) and *Raliegh Becket* (lead pilot of *Gypsy Danger*) reporting the exact same thing to LOCCENT (Local Command Center):

> LOCCENT: All ports sealed. Ready to submerge.

This implies that the Jaeger pilots have control over waterproof seals that can prevent the Jaegers from flooding.

Obviously, these seals can be damaged, which is exactly what happened when *Cherno Alpha* was destroyed.